# Why does Jackson think I have that value [assigned] because of the function [isAssigned]

Tags: java, spring, jackson

Jackson thinks that because of the method I have a value and need to assign it, although this is not the case. Same problem with [getDocumentView] if I use @JsonIgnore only on [isAssigned]. Although with methods in inherited class - no such problems.

I got an error

```
Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.utg.acadsys.api.model.order.OrderDetailView["orderLineItems"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.utg.acadsys.dao.model.order.OrderLineItem["assigned"])]
```

while sending that request in JSON format

```
{
    "existingSupplier": true,
    "systemInternalNumber": true,
    "orderLineItems": [
        {
            "count": 1,
            "vat": 20,
            "text": "123",
            "pricePerUnit": "1"
        }
    ],
    "subCompanyId": "39ee3eb9-605c-47b6-87e2-a20405708979",
    "approvalLineId": "04fa4a2c-9bce-11e8-aa4e-f23c910b0044",
    "email": null,
    "supplierId": "d83c7f3f-cd49-11e8-bf92-f23c910b0044",
    "deliveryDate": "2022-05-25",
    "reason": "12313",
    "note": "123123"
}
```

**OrderLineItem.java**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class OrderLineItem extends LineItem {

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Order order;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "orderLineItem")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<OrderLineAssignment> orderLineAssignments;

    public BigDecimal getAmountForCheck() {
        if (order.getCompany().isUseTotalPriceForCheck()) {
            return getTotalPrice();
        }
        return getPriceWithoutVat();
    }

    public boolean isAssigned() { // <---here
        return !orderLineAssignments.isEmpty();
    }

    public List<AssignedDocumentView> getAssignedDocumentsView() {
        if (!orderLineAssignments.isEmpty()) {
            List<AssignedDocumentView> assignedDocuments = new ArrayList<>();
            orderLineAssignments.forEach(assignment -> assignedDocuments.add(new AssignedDocumentView(assignment.getAssignedDocument().getId(), assignment.getAssignedDocument().getInvoiceNumber(), assignment.getAdditionDate())));
            return assignedDocuments;
        }
        return null;
    };
}
```

and extender class **LineItem.java**

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
public class LineItem extends EntityWithUUID {

    @NotNull
    private String text;
    @NotNull
    private BigDecimal count;
    @NotNull
    private BigDecimal pricePerUnit;
    private BigDecimal vat;

    public BigDecimal getTotalPrice() {
        if (count.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0) {
            return pricePerUnit.add(getVatAmount()).multiply(count);
        }
        return pricePerUnit.add(getVatAmount());
    }

    public BigDecimal getVatAmount() {
        if (vat != null) {
            return  pricePerUnit.multiply(vat.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100), 2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN));
        }

        return BigDecimal.ZERO;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPriceWithoutVat() {
        if (count.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0) {
            return pricePerUnit.multiply(count);
        }
        return pricePerUnit;
    }

    public boolean isVat() {
        return vat != null && vat.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) != 0;
    }
}
```

If I use @JsonIgnore - everything works properly, but I need it in GET requests.
If you need anything else, let me know and I'll attach it.

---

Yes, I managed to fix this by adding `@JsonIgnore` above the method. But I can no longer get the value of this method in GET requests as before with `vatAmount` and `priceWithoutVat`. And I'm wondering why this is, and how I can fix it. I've already googled options through `@JsonIgnoreProperties` to do a ban for POST requests and open for GET. (@JsonIgnoreProperties(allowSetters = false)) But it doesn't work as I have one method, not a value.

---

delomboked OrderLineItem.java

```
package com.utg.acadsys.dao.model.order;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.utg.acadsys.dao.model.LineItem;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class OrderLineItem extends LineItem {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Order order;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "orderLineItem")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<OrderLineAssignment> orderLineAssignments;

    public BigDecimal getAmountForCheck() {
        if (order.getCompany().isUseTotalPriceForCheck()) {
            return getTotalPrice();
        }
        return getPriceWithoutVat();
    }

    public boolean isAssigned() {
        return !orderLineAssignments.isEmpty();
    }

    public List<AssignedDocumentView> getAssignedDocumentsView() {
        if (!orderLineAssignments.isEmpty()) {
            List<AssignedDocumentView> assignedDocuments = new ArrayList<>();
            orderLineAssignments.forEach(assignment -> assignedDocuments.add(new AssignedDocumentView(assignment.getAssignedDocument().getId(), assignment.getAssignedDocument().getInvoiceNumber(), assignment.getAdditionDate())));
            return assignedDocuments;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("all")
    public Order getOrder() {
        return this.order;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("all")
    public List<OrderLineAssignment> getOrderLineAssignments() {
        return this.orderLineAssignments;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @SuppressWarnings("all")
    public void setOrder(final Order order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @SuppressWarnings("all")
    public void setOrderLineAssignments(final List<OrderLineAssignment> orderLineAssignments) {
        this.orderLineAssignments = orderLineAssignments;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't understood the part you wrote about JsonIgnore. I think JsonIgnore would have fixed this issue ?

Comment: @DeepakPatankar tried to explain as clearly as possible, and added an article at the end. thank you for your feedback)

Comment: @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY) helps ?

Comment: Can you please check whether @Setter is creating a setter for assigned field ?

Comment: @DeepakPatankar `JsonIgnoreProperties` does not work at all, as it is a method, not a value.

Comment: > Can you please check whether @Setter is creating a setter for assigned field ?
How ?

Comment: Is Setter an lombok annotation ? If yes, Can you please try using delombok ? Can you please see what is the autogenerated code  generated by @Setter annotation

Comment: This is the JavaBeans naming convention for boolean properties. A boolean property `assigned` has a `void setAssigned(boolean)` and `boolean isAssigned()` setter/getter pair (where any other type would have `type getAssigned()` instead). Jackson uses these naming conventions to determine which properties an object has. The NPE itself suggests that `orderLineAssignments` can be null, so maybe you should add a null check to `isAssigned()`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I replaced the method name with `getAssigned` but nothing has changed, the error is the same

Comment: That is because most parser following the JavaBeans convention will also consider `getAssigned` a getter for `assigned` even if it is a `boolean`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel and what should I do ?) no such problem with other variables in the inherited class, and I don't understand why

Comment: Use `@JsonIgnore`, which you already found out works, or rename that method so it isn't considered a JavaBeans property (e.g. just `assigned()`)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I don't get why, when I had no problem with it before, I was able to name the method with `get` at the beginning, or `is`

Comment: Did you use Jackson at that time? If yes, what changed between the time it worked and now?